# Spring expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring and Hibernate and I am trying to "wire" the classes that are necessary in order to *Autowire* a *Repository* inside a *Service*.

The Repository class extends CrudRepository

**StopRepository**

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "stop", path = "stop")
public interface StopRepository extends CrudRepository<StopJPA, Long> {

    StopJPA findById(@Param("id") Long id);

    StopJPA findByIdStop(@Param("idStop") String idStop);

    @Override
    void delete(StopJPA deleted);

    @Override
    List<StopJPA> findAll();

    // Optional<StopJPA> findOne(Long id);
    @Override
    StopJPA findOne(Long id);

    @Override
    StopJPA save(StopJPA persisted);

    void flush();

}
```

The Entity class.

**StopJPA**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stop")
@EntityListeners(RepoListener.class)
public class StopJPA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stop_description")
    private String stopDescription;

    @Column(name = "id_stop", nullable = false)
    private String idStop;

    public StopJPA() {
    }

    public StopJPA(String stopDescription, String idStop) {
        this.stopDescription = stopDescription;
        this.idStop = idStop;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStopDescription() {
        return stopDescription;
    }

    public void setStopDescription(String stopDescription) {
        this.stopDescription = stopDescription;
    }

    public String getIdStop() {
        return idStop;
    }

    public void setIdStop(String idStop) {
        this.idStop = idStop;
    }

}
```

And the Service class implementation:

**StopService**

```
@Service
final class RepoStopService {

@Service
final class RepoStopService {

    private final StopRepository stopRepository;

    @Autowired
    RepoStopService(StopRepository stopRepository) {
        this.stopRepository = stopRepository;
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately when i try to run it on server i get this exception:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   **Error creating bean with name 'repoStopService' defined in file
>   ...\RepoStopService.class:
>
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type
>   [com.project.app.services.repositories.StopRepository]: : No
>   qualifying bean of type**
>   [com.project.app.services.repositories.StopRepository] found for
>   dependency: **expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {};**
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.project.app.services.repositories.StopRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   .....

Does anyone know why Spring doesnt pick up the *@Repository* annotation?

---

My Configuration consists in 3 files.
An **AppInitializer** class that implements *WebApplicationInitializer* , a **WebMvcConfig** class that extends *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* and lastly a **PersistentContext** class.

**AppInitializer**

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "com.project.app.config";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);

    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
//@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.project.app" })

public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("hello");
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }
}
```

**PersistentContext**

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();

        String url = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.AMTAB_DS_URL);
        String user = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.AMTAB_DS_USERNAME);
        String pass = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.AMTAB_DS_PASSWORD);
        String driver = env.getProperty(SystemSettings.AMTAB_DS_DRIVER);

        // ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(user);
        ds.setPassword(pass);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project.app.services.entities");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        // Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
        // that is optimized for the used database.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getRequiredProperty(SystemSettings.HIBERNATE_DIALECT));

        // Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
        // SessionFactory is created or closed.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getRequiredProperty(SystemSettings.HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL));

        // Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
        // new database objects and schema elements
        // jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
        // env.getRequiredProperty(SystemSettings.HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));

        // If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
        // statements to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty(SystemSettings.HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        // If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will format the SQL
        // that is written to the console.
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                env.getRequiredProperty(SystemSettings.HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * Because we are using JPA, we have to create a transaction manager bean that integrates the
     * JPA provider with the Spring transaction mechanism. We can do this by using the
     * JpaTransactionManager class as the transaction manager of our application.
     *
     * We can configure the transaction manager bean by following these steps:
     *
     * -> Create a new JpaTransactionManager object. -> Configure the entity manager factory whose
     * transactions are managed by the created JpaTransactionManager object.
     **/
    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**SOLUTION**

I just needed to specify **also** the package of the repositories, because its a location that wont be searched by default --> **@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.app.services.repositories")**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/), you have to declare the `@ComponentScan` and the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations on your `@Configuration` class.

About the `@EnableJpaRepositories` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html):

> Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default.

Comment: well. i  updated my question and i included my configuration files. 
I did as you said but it gives me the same error as before. Is it (maybe) because i have more than on configurtation files??

Comment: ok..problem solved. I just needed to specify also the package of the repositories, because its a location that wont be searched by default  -->
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.app.services.repositories")

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error while using a repository class as an autowired.
You just need to use the below annotation according to your repository class.

**Mongo Repository**: @EnableMongoRepositories("spring.mongorestapi.repositories")

**JPA Repository**: @EnableJPARepositories("spring.jparestapi.repositories")